# How to tell the order of execution of formulas in the details section of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I was working on a report that had multiple formulas that used the same variable. All the formulas were used in the details section of the report. I noticed that the order the formulas were executing cause an incorrect total. I fixed this by using the ExecuteAfter() function. But it made me curious what rules Crystal uses to decide when to execute a formula.

I found this website http://book.soundonair.ru/sams/ch04lev1sec6.html which was quite informative, however as best as I can tell, all of the formulas of my report are executed in the Evaluates recurring formulas stage of Crystal Reports Processing EnginePass #1. I want to know within that stage, how Crystal decides to execute.

To try to make the question clearer:
If I have formula 1, formula 2 and formula 3. Formula A sets variable A to be a database value. Formula 2 sets Variable B to a value. Formula 3 sets variable C to A + B. All are in the details section of the report. How does Crystal decide which order to execute them in? Obviously I want Formula 3 to executer after formula 1 and formula 2.

Comment: You can execute things using the While...Records set of commands. For example, there is WhileReadingRecords, BeforeReadingRecords, WhilePrintingRecords. These allow you to control the evaluation process and workflow for your query. See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic736.html for the section 'Evaluation Time' for more details.

Comment: Another option is to put Formula 1 and 2 in your Report Header or Report Group Header 1, which will then execute before Formula 3 in your Details section.

Comment: Placing Formula 1 and 2 earlier I don't believe would work, since I need the variable set for each record. However, the link you provided does hint at the answer. Since Formula 1 and Formula 2 contain references to database fields, they are evaluated while reading records. Formula 3 does not directly contain any database fields, so by default Crystal evaluates it before reading records.